# Get all days of week to datagridview columns

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I use the following code to get all days of week to show them after each other between two dates and add them into datagridview columns :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < dtEnd.Subtract(dtStart).Days; j++)
  {
     TimeSpan counter = new TimeSpan(j, 0, 0, 0);
     dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText += (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString();
  }    
}
```

but this line

```
dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText += (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Causes an error. it says :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

How can I fix the problem?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                      ↓
dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText += (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

There should be an i instead of a j in above line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to use `i` as the index for the columns:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText += (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it's this line throwing the exception;

```
dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText += ...
```

You are using the counter variable 'i' to iterate over your grid columns, but the counter 'j' to set the values. If you have more days than columns, you'll get this exception. You might need to rethink your design here. Either add columns for each day, or use row. I don't know what you are intending, so beyond this, hard to advise.